# How to subtract or remove contents of context variable from string in Talend

Tags: talend, data-integration

In talend Open Studio if I have a context variable which points to a directory `C:/MyData` how can I subtract that from a directory string e.g. `C:/MyData/Folder/Sub/` so that I end up with `/Folder/Sub/` for additional processing

I tried storing the `C:/MyData/Folder/Sub/` in a variable `Path` and the context as as string in tMap use `Var.Path.replace(Var.ContextAsString, "")` but that didn't affect the output at all

Are there better ways to manipulate strings that represent directory paths using Talend tMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to declare a tMap variable.
Suppose the field containing the full path is "row1.fullpath" and the context variable is called root (containing "D:/MyData").
On the right part of the tMap, just write:

```
row1.fullpath.replace(context.root, "")
```

Comment: I tried that earlier but don't have the data as fields so needed to declare them as variables but you did make me retest the values and noticed I was searching for C:/MyData from a directorypath that was C:\MyData\Folder\Sub so it was never going to match (slash is different) but I was able to change the context Directory value without affecting the running of the job so the Var.Path.replace worked

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to example below and port it to tMap expression.

```
String s1 = "C:/MyData";
String s2 = "C:/MyData/Folder/Sub/";
String s3 = (s2.indexOf(s1) >= 0) ? s2.substring(s2.indexOf(s1) + s1.length()): s2;
System.out.println(s3);
```